# RecursiveIteratorIterator on multidimensional array with indexed elements

Tags: php, recursion, pdo, iterator, rows

i'm trying to iterate through this array and remove any type of ordering: (1, 2, 3, 4 etc.)

```
array( 0 => array ( 'col1' => 'value', 'col2' => 'value', 'col3' => 'value', 'col4' => value', 'col5' => 'value', 'col6' => array ( 'string' => array ( 'col7' => 'value' , 'col8' => 'value'), ), ), 

    1 => array ( 'col1' => 'value', 'col2' => 'value', 'col3' => 'value', 'col4' => array ( ), 'col5' => 'value', 'col6' => array ( 'string' => array ( ), ),  ),

     2 => array ( 'col1' => 'value', 'col2' => 'value', 'col3' => 'value', 'col4' => array ( ), 'col5' => 'value', 'col6' => array ( 'string' => array ( ), ), ), )
```

using the following code:

```
    foreach($json['orders']['cnr_output_ship_to_header'] as $header)
{



   $iterator_orders = new \IteratorIterator(new \ArrayIterator($header));
    $iterator_guests = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new\RecursiveArrayIterator($header['guests']['cnr_output_guest_detail']));
    $iterator_items = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveArrayIterator($header['items']['cnr_output_item_detail']));


$orders = (array)iterator_to_array($iterator_orders,true); 
$guests = (array)iterator_to_array($iterator_guests,true);
$items = (array)iterator_to_array($iterator_items,true);




pdo_insert('cnr_output_ship_to_header', (array)$orders);
pdo_insert('cnr_output_guest_detail', (array)$guests);
pdo_insert('cnr_output_item_detail', (array)$items);


}
```

but its removing elements elements 0 and 1. Any idea how to include [0] and [1]?

Comment: What does this $json['orders']['cnr_output_ship_to_header'] contain ? The sample array provided and the iterated one are different.

Comment: each ['cnr_output_ship_to_header'] consists of a index that contains all those other indexs. If the index inside of the $json['orders']['cnr_output_ship_to_header'] index has multiple subelements, all but the last element is missing from $guests or $items. It has to do with the fact that my pdo_insert function is unable to insert numbered/ordered arrays. How would I flatten the default numbering system when iterating through $iterator_guests or $iterator_items sub elements? $Orders works just fine by the way.

Comment: $json['orders']['cnr_output_ship_to_header'] looks like:

`array( 'col1' => 'value', 'col2' => 'value', 'col3' => 'value', 'col4' => 'value', 'col5' => 'value', ['col6' => 'value','col7' => 'value',] )

array( 'col1' => 'value', 'col2' => 'value', 'col3' => 'value', 'col4' => 'value', 'col5' => 'value', ['col6' => 'value','col7' => 'value',] )

array( 'col1' => 'value', 'col2' => 'value', 'col3' => 'value', 'col4' => 'value', 'col5' => 'value', ['col6' => 'value','col7' => 'value',] )` where `[]` is placed to notate empty.The others indexs look like the example in the beginning of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I scratched JSON and used simpleXML, foreach worked as mentioned.